# Associated primes and finite base change

Tags: commutative-algebra, noetherian

Let $R$ be an integrally closed commutative Noetherian integral domain.  Let $R \subseteq S$ be a ring extension such that $S$ is also an integral domain and is finite as an $R$-module.  Let $I$ be an ideal of $R$.  What can we say about the following two sets $$\operatorname{Ass}_R(R/I) \quad \text{ and }\quad \pi(\operatorname{Ass}_S(S/IS))$$
where $\pi: \operatorname{Spec} S \rightarrow \operatorname{Spec} R$ is the usual map of prime spectra?  Is there a containment in either direction?  I know they are equal if $S$ is faithfully flat over $R$, but I don't know what happens in the module-finite case.

Comment: @user121097 Yes, the conditions are enough to ensure $IS \neq S$ (assuming of course that $I \neq R$).  It's enough to show this when $I$ is a maximal ideal, and the latter follows from the "lying over" property of integral extensions (and after all, every module-finite extension is integral).  That is, the map $\pi: \operatorname{Spec} S \rightarrow \operatorname{Spec} R$ is surjective.

Comment: Just a remark: it is true that $\text{Min}(R/I) = \pi(\text{Min}(S/IS))$, where $\text{Min}$ is the set of minimal primes. Thus any interesting things could only occur in the embedded primes, but the behavior of these is still mysterious (to me). I think that even the special case where $R$ is regular, and $R \subseteq S$ is a Noether normalization (if $S$ is either finitely generated over a field, or complete) is already very interesting. Notice that in this last case we may assume $S$ is not Cohen-Macaulay, otherwise flatness saves the day